# how to remove parent element if it exists?

Tags: jquery, tags, element, parent

So, sometimes, my output will look like this:

```
<p><img src="someimage.jpg" /></p>
<p>A new paragraph</p>
```

Other times, it will look like this:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg />
<p>A new paragraph</p>
```

I'm trying to write some sort of "if" statement where, if the first p element in the markup surrounds an image tag, it will pull:

```
$j("p:eq(1)")
```

Otherwise, it will pull:

```
$j("p:eq(0)")
```

Alternatively, I could find all the img tags and if it's surrounded by

tags, remove those, but I'm not sure which one is better, or how to do either...

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
if($j("img:eq(0)").parent().get(0).tagName == "p") {
      var pt = $j("p:eq(1)");
} else {
      var pt = $j("p:eq(0)");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var paragraphsWithoutImages = $('p').not(':has(img)')
```

([Live example](http://jsbin.com/olopi))

Answer (score 1):

This will grab the paragraph not containing an image, which fits your limited sample:

```
var pt = $("p:not(:has(img))");
```

It's probably the case that your actual markup will be more complex than this but there are many variations on this that you could do.

Answer (score 0):

$('img').unwrap('p');

if you wish to remove the first parent element, just use .unwrap();

PS: note if u ara using jQuery in compability mode and if you need, change $ to $j